# css flex: разместить эл-ты в ДВЕ строки на определенном разрешении

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Подскажите, как решить такую задачу.

Хочу, чтобы при уменьшении экрана вниз смещался не один блок, а сразу три.
Т.е. чтобы на разрешениях, где все 6 блоков в одну строку не помещаются, **сразу 3 из них смещались вниз**.

У меня сейчас по 1 вниз переходят. Получается, что в верхнем ряду 5 блоков, а в нижнем 1, при дальнейшем уменьшении - 4 и 2...

Вот код:

```css
  body {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.choice {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url(Plan.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  /* Положение фона */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Отменяем повторение фона */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

figcaption {
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .choice:nth-of-type(2n + 1) figure {
    float: none;
  }
```

```html
<nav class='wrapper'>
  <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/database.html';">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Последнее обновление</a></h1>
      <img src='Today-final.jpg' alt='Все квартиры за сегодня' />
      <figcaption>Адреса и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/area.html';">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>По районам Петербурга</a></h1>
      <p><img src='Metro-distr-final.jpg' alt='Квартиры по районам и метро'></p>
      <figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам СПб
        <br />и станциям метро</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/sut.html';">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Посуточные квартиры</a></h1>
      <p><img src='Sutochno-final.jpg' alt='Аренда на несколько дней'></p>
      <figcaption>
        <br />Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>

  <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/database.html';">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Последнее обновление</a></h1>
      <img src='Today-final.jpg' alt='Все квартиры за сегодня' />
      <figcaption>Адреса и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/area.html';">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>По районам Петербурга</a></h1>
      <p><img src='Metro-distr-final.jpg' alt='Квартиры по районам и метро'></p>
      <figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам СПб
        <br />и станциям метро</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/sut.html';">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Посуточные квартиры</a></h1>
      <p><img src='Sutochno-final.jpg' alt='Аренда на несколько дней'></p>
      <figcaption>
        <br />Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: То есть тегу figure задать width в процентах на опр. разрешениях? Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Нет, не получилось. Блоки смещаются так же по одному. Просто изменяется их ширина при изменении экрана.

Comment: Я щас комп включу и попробую сам..погодите 20 минут

Comment: Максим, получилось у Вас?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77486/discussion-between--and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="wrapper d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/database.html';">

              </section>
              <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/area.html';">

              </section>
              <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/sut.html';">

              </section>

              <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/database.html';">

              </section>
              <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/area.html';">

              </section>
              <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/sut.html';">

              </section>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>


/* CSS */

body {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.choice {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url(Plan.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}

.justify-content-between { 
  justify-content: space-between;
 } 

 .flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }


.container { width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; } 

 .d-flex { display: flex; }

 @media screen and (max-width: 1430px) {
  .container { width: 60%; }
}
```

Вот, у меня все работает, при разрешении ниже чем 1430 блоки будут по 3 в ряд, потом по 2

Comment: Попробую, спасибо! К ночи ближе освобожусь и попытаюсь так сделать.

Comment: О! Все получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: @Наталья Пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
   <div class="wrapper__wrapper d-flex justify-content-between">
      //блоки
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__wrapper d-flex justify-content-between">
      //блоки
   </div>
</div>
```

flex-wrap - когда не будут помещаться все в строку, то сами перепрыгнут, а wrapper__wrapper - блок в котором ваши 3 блока, только задайте wrapper__wrapper ширину

Comment: Ваш метод решает задачу, но при этом появляется новая. Эти блоки-обертки по три блока при дальнейшем уменьшении экрана так и остаются сгруппированы. И на разрешениях, где должно быть по 2 блока в ряд, получается 2 на первой строке + 1 на второй; 2 - на третьей + 1 на четвертой.

Comment: @Наталья тогда попробуйте обернуть их все в один блок 
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
//блоки
</div>
Таким образом они будут перепрыгивать по мере допустимого разрешения, и если их парное количество то в одной строке будет равное кол-во блоков

Comment: Не знаю, верно ли я Вас поняла. Обернула все содержимое блока nav в  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">. Результат такой же, как без этой обертки - блоки смещаются по одному.

Comment: @Наталья попробуйте следующим образом,
оберните свой nav в container и задайте ему ширину 90% и margin: 0 auto; и на брейкпоинте когда блоки начнут перепрыгивать смените ширину контейнера так, чтобы блоки в ряд  были как надо

Comment: @Наталья 
<div class="container">
   <nav class="wrapper d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
      //blocks
   </nav>
</div>

.container { width: 90%; margin 0 auto; } //на брейкпоинтах меняете его ширину пока блоки не станут так как надо вам

Comment: Все по прежнему - блоки смещаются по одному :((

Comment: Маленькое уточнение. Пришлось добавить inherit: none; для того самого .container. А то, видимо, родительские стили "путались под ногами". Огромное спасибо!